# Is there a way of selecting the last item of a list with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Say I have a list as follows:

- item1
- item2
- item3

Is there a CSS selector that will allow me to directly select the last item of a list? In this case item 3.

Cheers!

Comment: I ran through the li:last-child selector earlier; however I cannot use it as it does not work in IE.

In this case I do not have control over the HTML, so I cannot tag the first and last childs accordingly.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you're not going to get this to do what you want.  You could do it with javascript if you have control over that & you want to go down that road, but it's a dark, scary road with dragons ;)

Comment: The correct answer as of the browser support in 2013 is by OZZIE. The outdated answer is by Glenn Slaven.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not that i'm aware of.  The traditional solution is to tag the first & last items with class="first" & class="last" so you can identify them.

The CSS psudo-class [first-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) will get you the first item but not all browsers support it. CSS3 will have [last-child too](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#last-child-pseudo) (this is currently supported by Firefox, Safari but not IE 6/7/beta 8)

Answer (score 6):

Until it's properly supported, you'll need to add a class to 'last' items, as suggested. You don't have to do this manually, though. If you can take a javascript hit, take a look at either:

- [the jQuery :last-child selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild)
- [Keeping Your Elements’ Kids in Line with Offspring](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/keepelementskidsinlinewithoffspring) (a list apart article by Alex Bischoff), a specific, lighter-weight method

Either will avoid 'polluting' your markup, and are perfectly acceptable if your style is a 'nice addition' as opposed to a 'must have' design feature.

Comment: This seems still to be the case if you're looking for x-platform support.

Comment: +1 for jQuery reference. If you don't control the markup, as it is the case in a lot of product/template skinning exercises, this is really the only (and easiest) way to success with broad x-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The answer for this question should be updated! IE9 + Firefox (for a while back) + Chrome, Safari all support: `last-of-type` or `last-child`